# Why is the return function in my debounce function never called? Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debouncing

I am learning about debouncing, and the concept makes sense, but I don't know why the arrow function that my debounce function returns is never run.

```
    public debounce = (func, delay, event) => {
    console.log(func, delay, event.target.value);
    let debounceTimer;
    return (...args) => {
      clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
      console.log(func, delay, event.target.value);
      debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, [event.target.value]), delay);
    };
  };
  public resolveInput(event) {
    console.log('resolved', event);
  }
```

And this is how I call the debouncer:

```
<input (input)="debounce(resolveInput, 1000, $event)" />
```

Any explanation would be helpful. I understand that we need to return a function so that the setTimeout exists in its own scope so that we can reset it whenever we receive a new input before the time has run out, but I don't know why that return function isn't being invoked.

Comment: Because on the `input` event, the code `debounce(resolveInput, 1000, $event)` will be called. This is not the same as `element.oninput = debounce(resolveInput, 1000)` in Javascript, which calls `debounce` once here, and binds *its return value* as the `oninput` event handler. A hint that something's wrong here should be that not `debounce` should receive the `$event`, but its return function should.

Comment: @deceze is there a way to do this natively in angular then? Do I just target my input and then put `element.oninput = debounce(resolveInput, 1000)` in the ts file? And then how would the $event make it to the `resolveInput` function if I don't specify it as an argument? Thank you for your response by the way (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need arrow function here.

You can write directly this:

```js
public debounceTimer;

public debounce = (func, delay, event) => {
  console.log(func, delay, event.target.value);
  clearTimeout(this.debounceTimer);
  console.log(func, delay, event.target.value);
  this.debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => func.apply(this, [event.target.value]), delay);

};

public resolveInput(event) {
  console.log('resolved', event);
}
```